# Hibernate ignores class & mapping

Tags: c#, spring, hibernate, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I seem to have this issue a lot.

I setup a new class.
I setup a new hbm.xml mapping and make it an embedded resource.
I'll run my application and it will tell me I have a mismatch of attribute names ~ most commonly a case issue in the name of an attribute between the class and the mapping.  Specific error "no getter / setter" for the name as shown in the mapping.

But that is not the point of this quesiton, I fix that.

Now all typos are fixed but now hibernate doesn't do anything.  It just totally ignores the integration.  It doesn't call SQL server, I know because I trace that on the SQL server side.  I can even change the name of the view the mapping is pointed to and it is as if I don't even need a mapping ~ because hibernate is just ignoring it and everything in regard to this class.

If I turn on hibernate logging (log4net) to DEBUG level.  Other sql entities are shown in the logging but not my new one.

How do you troubleshoot this?

In the past I've seen sometimes how something isn't perfectly jiving between the mapping and the SQL entity.  And sometimes when I get those two ducks in a row things start to work.

Again, how do you troubleshoot this?  What is nHibernate doing to conparing the mapping to SQL and where it finds soemthing it doesn't like it just ignores it.

This is my class:

```
public class Nodes {
    public virtual Int64 Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Int64 NodeId { get; set; }
    public virtual string Node { get; set; }
}
```

This is my map:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" auto-import="false" assembly="Prj" namespace="Prj.Nodes.Domain" default-lazy="false">
  <class name ="Nodes" table="dbo.vNodes" dynamic-update="false" lazy="false">
    <cache usage="read-only"/>
    <id name="Id" column="Id" type="Int64">
      <generator class="native" />
    </id>
    <property name="NodeId" />
    <property name="Node" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is my SQL:

```
create table Nodes
(
    Id bigint identity(1,1) not null
    , NodeId bigint not null
    , Node varchar(10) null
)

insert into Nodes (NodeId, Node) values (100, 'Hello')
go

create view vNodes
as
    select 
        Id
        , NodeId
        , Node
    from Nodes with (NoLock)
go
```

And this is my application (method in a from a DOA):

```
using NHibernate;
public List<Nodes> LoadNodes()
{
    ICriteria c = NHibernateSessionManager.Instance.GetSession().CreateCriteria(typeof(Nodes));
    List<Nodes> n = c.List<Nodes>().ToList<Nodes>();
    return n;
}
```

Noting is logged about Nodes/vNodes in the hibernate logging file ~ not even at the DEBUG level.  Other methods and classes in the same DAO are logged. But nothing about this one.

I would rather have some error some where helping me to understand what I need to fix.

I use this pattern/architecture a lot and it works fantastically. But for on to many occasions when I start a new class/entity/integration and am first getting the ducks in a row.

Respect & appreciation

Answer (score 0):

Just so happens today issue is the the mapping's file name was "Nodes.hdm..xml".
no idea how the two dots got int there for the file extension.

Something I'd forgotten is how hibernate uses the file's name in the resources list of embedded resources in the executable.  Any small thing wrong in the file names and hibernate won't know it has a resource it needs to use.